# How to multiple two rows which as same ID but different column values and return a single row in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table at a customer ID level where I need to group by customer ID and multiply different values in  row & column.

Eg:
Table a

| ID | Qnt |
| --- | --- |
| ab1234 | 20 |
| xy123 | 30 |
| gh123 | 10 |

Table b :

| ID | cap | mkt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab1234 | 1 | 2 |
| xy123 | 1 | 5 |
| xy123 | 2 | 2 |
| gh123 | 1 | 5 |
| xy123 | 3 | 0.5 |

Expected output
When ID = xy123
Then I should get below record

| ID | Qnt | b.cap | b.mkt | c.cap | c.mkt | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy123 | 30 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 600 |

Note : Consider only 1 & 2 in cap column

When ID = gh123

| ID | Qnt | b.cap | b.mkt | c.cap | c.mkt | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| gh123 | 10 | 1 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 50 |

When cap is only 1 for ID =gh123 then multiply qnt*b.cap*b.mkt
Which is 10*1*5 = 50

```
Select a.id,
       b.cap,
       b.mkt,
       c.cap,
       c.mkt,
       (a.qnt*a.cap*a.mkt*b.cap*b.mkt) as output
From   table1 a
       Left join table2 b On a.id = b.id
       Inner join table2 c On b.id=c.id
Where  b.cap=1
and    c.cap=2
and    a.id = 'xy123';
```

This code works for xy123 where cap is 1 and 2 but doesn't work for id gh123.

Need SQL query and I'm not looking for PL/SQL or using cursors.

Comment: So for each ID is Qnt always going to be the same value? If not, what are the rules for how to treat this scenario?

Comment: please add tables and data for table1 and table2 so that we can reproduce your problem

Comment: Yes Qnt will remain the same for respective ID's

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: oh, is this oracle or mysql?  please pick the correct one

Comment: This is hard without a unique identifier... Please tag the correct RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

In both Oracle and MySQL, you can use (assuming `mkt > 0`):

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       a.qnt,
       ROUND(a.qnt * b.total, 2) AS total
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN (
         SELECT id,
                EXP(SUM(LN(cap * mkt))) AS total
         FROM   table2
         WHERE  cap IN (1, 2)   
         GROUP BY id
       ) b
       ON a.id = b.id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID VARCHAR(10), Qnt INT);
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID VARCHAR(10), cap INT, mkt INT);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, qnt)
SELECT 'ab1234', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  30 FROM DUAL

INSERT INTO table2 (id, cap, mkt)
SELECT 'ab1234', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  2, 2 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| id | qnt | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ab1234 | 20 | 40 |
| xy123 | 30 | 600 |

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/34Ugpnzu) [MySQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uHAEgVbN)

Comment: if there are 0's in the data, this will produce NULL; probably should be `COALESCE(EXP(SUM(LN(cap * mkt))),0)`

Answer (score 0):

You fail because if cap = 2 doesn't exist, the query doesn't work as the INNER JOIN  would remove the row.

adding c as `LEFT JOIN` and replacing all NULL vaues with 1 should give a result

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID VARCHAR(10), Qnt INT);
```

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID VARCHAR(10), cap INT, mkt INT);
```

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id, qnt)
SELECT 'ab1234', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  30 FROM DUAL
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, cap, mkt)
SELECT 'ab1234', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  2, 2 FROM DUAL
```

> ```
> Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
Select a.id,
       b.cap,
       b.mkt,
       c.cap,
       c.mkt,
       (a.qnt*COALESCE(b.cap,1)*(COALESCE(b.mkt,1))*COALESCE(c.cap,1)*(COALESCE(c.mkt,1))) as output
From   table1 a
       Left join table2 b On a.id = b.id AND b.cap=1
       LEFT join table2 c On a.id=c.id AND c.cap=2
```

| id | cap | mkt | cap | mkt | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab1234 | 1 | 2 | *null* | *null* | 40 |
| xy123 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 600 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/iWqIVwlA)

Comment: Thankq so much ! But the above query doesn't work for ID "ab123" where it has only one record as "cap 1 " and multiplies twice like

Comment: @AravindBalakrishnan no problem, with the data provided by the others i fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

While EXP(SUM(LN(...))) can be used to emulate a PRODUCT aggregate function, as shown in MT0's answer, you can in general implement arbitrary aggregate functions using recursive ctes.  In mysql syntax:

```
with recursive
customer_rownum as (
  select id, qnt, cap, mkt, row_number() over (partition by id, qnt) as rownum
  from customer
),
customer_iterate_product as (
  select id, qnt, rownum, cap * mkt as cap_mkt_product
  from customer_rownum
  where rownum = 1
  union all
  select cp.id, cp.qnt, mult.rownum, cp.cap_mkt_product * mult.cap * mult.mkt
  from customer_iterate_product cp
  inner join customer_rownum mult on mult.id=cp.id and mult.qnt=cp.qnt and mult.rownum=cp.rownum + 1
),
customer_final_product as (
  select id, qnt, cap_mkt_product
  from (
     select id, qnt, cap_mkt_product, row_number() over (partition by id, qnt order by cip.rownum desc) as rownum
     from customer_iterate_product cip
  ) foo
  where rownum = 1
)
select id, qnt, qnt * cap_mkt_product as output
from customer_final_product
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qXc7HDSi)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can `PIVOT` the second table based on `cap` value and then join and multiply the pivoted values together using `COALESCE` to handle `NULL` values:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       a.qnt,
       NVL2(b.mkt1, 1, NULL) AS cap1,
       b.mkt1 AS mkt1,
       NVL2(b.mkt2, 2, NULL) AS cap2,
       b.mkt2 AS mkt2,
       a.qnt
       * COALESCE(1 * b.mkt1, 1)
       * COALESCE(2 * b.mkt2, 1) AS total
FROM   table1 a
       INNER JOIN (
         table2
         PIVOT (SUM(mkt) FOR cap IN (1 AS mkt1, 2 AS mkt2)) b
       )
       ON a.id = b.id;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID VARCHAR(10), Qnt INT);
CREATE TABLE table2 (ID VARCHAR(10), cap INT, mkt INT);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, qnt)
SELECT 'ab1234', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  30 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'gh123',  10 FROM DUAL

INSERT INTO table2 (id, cap, mkt)
SELECT 'ab1234', 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  2, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'gh123',  1, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'xy123',  3, 0.5 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

| ID | QNT | CAP1 | MKT1 | CAP2 | MKT2 | TOTAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xy123 | 30 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 2 | 600 |
| ab1234 | 20 | 1 | 2 | *null* | *null* | 40 |
| gh123 | 10 | 1 | 5 | *null* | *null* | 50 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9XYIDGRw)

Answer (score 0):

When there is a task that envolves inter-rows/inter-columns calculations one of the options is to use [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm). It behaves quite like excel sheet alowing you to address any particular row/column/cell.
With sample data provided...

```sql
WITH
    tbl_a (ID, QNT) AS
        ( Select 'ab1234', 20 From Dual Union All
          Select 'xy123',  30 From Dual Union All
          Select 'gh123',  10 From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_b (ID, CAP, MKT) as
        ( Select 'ab1234',  1,   2 From Dual Union All
          Select 'xy123',   1,   5 From Dual Union All
          Select 'xy123',   2,   2 From Dual Union All
          Select 'gh123',   1,   5 From Dual Union All
          Select 'xy123',   3, 0.5 From Dual 
        ),
```

... you could MODEL your data creating a grid with all the data participating in calculation (with calculation itself) in the same row. Oracle's MODEL clause is both fast and reliable. Here it is done creating a cte named modeled_tbl...
Comments in code...

```sql
  modeled_tbl AS
    ( Select    *
      From  ( Select    a.ID, b.CAP, a.QNT, b.CAP "B_CAP", b.MKT "B_MKT"
              From      tbl_a a
              Inner Join tbl_b b ON(b.ID = a.ID)
              Where   b.CAP <= 2
            )
          MODEL   Partition By  ( ID  )     -- <-- clasic partition by clause
                  Dimension By  ( CAP )     -- <-- dimension (referenced below within square brackets) with partition column uniquely defines rows
                  Measures    ( QNT, B_CAP, B_MKT, 0 "C_CAP", 0 "C_MKT", 0 "OUTPUT" )  -- <-- columns that you can define values to using row/col addressings and conditionings
          RULES ( B_CAP[1]   = CV(CAP),     -- <-- rules section - here you can do all transformations/aggregations/calculations etc. with or without conditions - CV() is Current Value of (dimension)
                  B_MKT[1]   = B_MKT[CV()], 
                  C_CAP[1]   = Nvl(Max(B_CAP)[CAP = 2], B_CAP[1]),
                  C_MKT[1]   = Nvl(Max(B_MKT)[CAP = 2], B_MKT[1]),
                  OUTPUT[1]  = QNT[1] * B_CAP[1] * B_MKT[1] * 
                               Case When C_CAP[1]= 1 And B_CAP[1] = 1 Then 1 Else C_CAP[1] End * 
                               Case When C_CAP[1]= 1 And B_CAP[1] = 1 Then 1 Else C_MKT[1] End 
                )
    )
```

```sql
/*      (modeled_tbl)   R e s u l t :
ID            CAP        QNT      B_CAP      B_MKT      C_CAP      C_MKT     OUTPUT
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
xy123           1         30          1          5          2          2        600
xy123           2         30          2          2          0          0          0
ab1234          1         20          1          2          1          2         40
gh123           1         10          1          5          1          5         50   */
```

NOTE: You can do your own conditionings or calculations or whatever you need in the code above to fine tune the resultset that you want to get out.
... the above resultset could now be used to get your expected result from the question.

```sql
-- M a i n    S Q L   ( using modeled_tbl cte )
SELECT  ID, QNT, B_CAP, B_MKT, C_CAP, C_MKT, OUTPUT
FROM    modeled_tbl
WHERE   CAP = 1
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ID            QNT      B_CAP      B_MKT      C_CAP      C_MKT     OUTPUT
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
xy123          30          1          5          2          2        600
ab1234         20          1          2          1          2         40
gh123          10          1          5          1          5         50    */
```

If you want to include the third value where it is present (xy123) just add it to the modeling and main sql like below. You can do pretty much whatever you want...

```sql
  modeled_tbl AS
    ( Select    *
      From  ( Select    a.ID, b.CAP, a.QNT, b.CAP "B_CAP", b.MKT "B_MKT"
              From      tbl_a a
              Inner Join tbl_b b ON(b.ID = a.ID)
            )
          MODEL   Partition By  ( ID  )     -- <-- clasic partition by clause
                  Dimension By  ( CAP )     -- <-- dimension (referenced below within square brackets) with partition column uniquely defines rows
                  Measures    ( QNT, B_CAP, B_MKT, 0 "C_CAP", 0 "C_MKT", 0 "D_CAP", 0 "D_MKT", 0 "OUTPUT" )  -- <-- columns that you can define values to using row/col addressings and conditionings
          RULES ( B_CAP[1]   = CV(CAP),     -- <-- rules section - here you can do all transformations/aggregations/calculations etc. with or without conditions - CV() is Current Value of (dimension)
                  B_MKT[1]   = B_MKT[CV()], 
                  C_CAP[1]   = Nvl(Max(B_CAP)[CAP = 2], B_CAP[1]),
                  C_MKT[1]   = Nvl(Max(B_MKT)[CAP = 2], B_MKT[1]),
                  D_CAP[1]   = Nvl(Max(B_CAP)[CAP = 3], B_CAP[1]),
                  D_MKT[1]   = Nvl(Max(B_MKT)[CAP = 3], B_MKT[1]),
                  OUTPUT[1]  = QNT[1] * B_CAP[1] * B_MKT[1] * 
                               Case When C_CAP[1]= 1 And B_CAP[1] = 1 Then 1 Else C_CAP[1] End * 
                               Case When C_CAP[1]= 1 And B_CAP[1] = 1 Then 1 Else C_MKT[1] End *
                               Case When D_CAP[1]= 1 And B_CAP[1] = 1 Then 1 Else D_CAP[1] End * 
                               Case When D_CAP[1]= 1 And B_CAP[1] = 1 Then 1 Else D_MKT[1] End
                )
    )
```

```sql
SELECT  ID, QNT, B_CAP, B_MKT, C_CAP, C_MKT, D_CAP, D_MKT, OUTPUT
FROM    modeled_tbl
WHERE CAP = 1
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
ID            QNT      B_CAP      B_MKT      C_CAP      C_MKT      D_CAP      D_MKT     OUTPUT
------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
xy123          30          1          5          2          2          3        0,5        900
ab1234         20          1          2          1          2          1          2         40
gh123          10          1          5          1          5          1          5         50    */
```